How to solve this ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.6.0?
I'm using a demo on Colab notebook called Deep Exemplar Based Video Colorization. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Y1XTlTdUG-2LzrH1Vnr_osg9BQavfYsz?usp=sharing
Worked swimmingly for four years until this monday. In the Run Environment cell - I get the error below. I'm not sure what the protocol is here, but I thought I'd just post the Run environment cell, after I run it, which displays the errors. As it was working fine till last sunday, does anyone know if there was a recent update which could have caused the issue?
Run Environment Command cell:
# seems to be a colab bug, need to install previous version for pytorch
!pip install torch==1.6.0 torchvision==0.7.0
!pip install -q moviepy
!apt install imagemagick
!pip install imageio==2.4.1

%cd Deep-Exemplar-based-Video-Colorization/
! pip install -r requirements.txt

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.6.0 (from versions: 1.11.0, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.5.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.6.0

--------------------------------
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
moviepy 1.0.3 requires imageio<3.0,>=2.5; python_version >= "3.4", but you have imageio 2.4.1 which is incompatible.
scikit-image 0.24.0 requires imageio>=2.33, but you have imageio 2.4.1 which is incompatible.

------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Failed building wheel for scipy
  Running setup.py clean for scipy
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py clean did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for scipy
---------------------------------------------


I don't know of a specific update since alst sunday, but the versions specified in the requirements.txt (scikit==1.2) and also directly in the cell (torch==1.6) are not compatible with python 3.10, which is in colab for quite some time.
The best approach is to use a python version that supports all versions required in this demo. You could try to update the package versions required in requirements.txt to a higher version compatible with python 3.10, but then you have no guarantee that the module you are trying to use still works.
To achieve the downgrade of python, add a new cell to the very top containing
!sudo apt-get install python3.7
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 1
!sudo apt install python3.7-distutils
!curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.7/get-pip.py | sudo python3.7


thankyou I'll try this. The program is working again at present, even with all the errors.

This problem is because there isn't a version of your library compatible with the version of Python you are using.
Collab has upgraded its python version and it isn't compatible anymore with the four years old torch=1.6.0.
You can:

try to upgrade torch for a newer version. The newest one is 2.5.0. Here is the release history: https://pypi.org/project/torch/#history
try to use an older Python in your Collab notebook (I don't know if it is possible).


thanks Neves. Can you direct me to a tutorial on how to upgrade torch?

I might also add that the program ran and completed successfully for over a year with these errors being displayed.

I've added the Run environment command. See below. This is last update in 2022 by the developer.
